# How to access a function defined globaly outside of the class

Tags: python, global-variables

I am new to Python, and I am facing a problem:

```
def a():  ....

class b :   
    def c():
         x=a()
```

My function `a` is defined outside of the class, and I need it to access inside the class in function `c`. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it using `a()`, it's available through the global module scope:

```
def a():
    return "test"


class b:
    def c(self):
        x = a()
        print x

b().c()  # prints "test"
```

Also see this thread: [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)